# qmake on mingw creates windows-style path within Makefile

Tags: makefile, mingw, qmake, mingw-w64

I'm using qmake inside Mingw64/MSYS.

Inside the pro files I need to refer to a relative path (DESTDIR=../bin) so testcase executables are placed correctly.

When running the make check target, the generated Makefile code contains
a line with a windows path notation:

```
cd ..\bin && /C/Projects/tests/Testcase/src/target_wrapper.sh  ./Testcase.exe
```

Changing to ..\bin will fail, because ..bin is not found:

```
/bin/sh: Zeile 0: cd: ..bin: No such file or directory
```

I can't find the reason why qmake mixes windows and *nix notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is caused by a patch applied by mingw:

https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues/1117

Answer (score 0):

qmake is target specific. There is a different installation of qmake for each target you have configured (*e.g.* Mingw64, msvc2015_32, msvc2013_64, *etc.*).  It sounds like you are executing a Windows (MSCV) targeted qmake instead of the Mingw64 version.  You may need to explicitly invoke the correct version by specifying the complete path to it.